# Can I manually add libraries to libs/armeabi-v7a?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a library .so file that I want to be packaged in libs/armeabi-v7a.

I know that the right way to do this is by defining this in Android.mk as a PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY, and have ndk-build automatically pick this up.
Normally this is golden.

However, my library has a version number (which I cannot modify), i.e. libbubba.so.0.5.4.
And ndk-build will fail, saying that the library needs to end with .so.

So I am looking for a way to manually add this file to the package.
If I just manually put it in the libs/armeabi-v7a directory, it does not get packaged when I build.

Anyone done this?  Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you modify the file name? I'm not sure android even lets you load the library if it doesn't end with .so

Comment: You can load it with System.load(), instead of System.loadLibrary().  Good idea, but I've tried it.  Can't just change the name, because the library is internally named libbubba.so.0.5.4.  If I simply change the name to libbubba.so, when I load it, my app complains that it never found libbubba.so.0.5.4 -- as that is the internal name it linked to.

Comment: Right - but will Android Resource Manager actually pack a file ending with .0.5.4?

Comment: You will probably need to change the name internally in the library.  Is this even an android library?  You really should do it with the library's build system, but at a very crude level, my impression is that ELF uses null-terminated strings internally, so you could probably use sed on the binary to replace them with shorter versions having an earlier null.